# what is the name of the sum of all numbers inside a number, including the number itself?

Tags: terminology

ex.: 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=55

this it what I mean by "numbers inside "10", including "10" ...I was in bed, thinking of a quick way to calculate that, but with a way bigger number ( ex.: 149581730012375017587312) and I quickly came up with a simple equation : a((a/2)+0.5)=x    where "a" is the number and "x" is the sum of all numbers inside it...so, what is the name for that "x"? Since the same thing but with multiplications is a factorial, and this equation is so simple, I assumed there is already a name for it....

Comment: Funny you saying that $1,2,\ldots ,9$ are in $10$, because they actually are.

Answer (score 2):

This is called “the $n$th [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)”.